# How to deserialize element with list of attributes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, attributes

Hi I have the following Xml to deserialize:

```
<RootNode>
    <Item
      Name="Bill"
      Age="34"
      Job="Lorry Driver"
      Married="Yes" />
    <Item
      FavouriteColour="Blue"
      Age="12"
    <Item
      Job="Librarian"
       />
    </RootNote>
```

How can I deserialize the Item element with a list of attribute key value pairs when I dont know the key names or how many attributes there will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`XmlAnyAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyattributeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to specify that arbitrary attributes will be serialized and deserialized into an [`XmlAttribute []`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property or field when using `XmlSerializer`.

For instance, if you want to represent your attributes as a `Dictionary<string, string>`, you could define your `Item` and `RootNode` classes as follows, using a proxy `XmlAttribute[]` property to convert the dictionary from and to the required `XmlAttribute` array:

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyAttribute]
    public XmlAttribute[] XmlAttributes
    {
        get
        {
            if (Attributes == null)
                return null;
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            return Attributes.Select(p => { var a = doc.CreateAttribute(p.Key); a.Value = p.Value; return a; }).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                Attributes = null;
            else
                Attributes = value.ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a.Value);
        }
    }
}

public class RootNode
{
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S4mz9a).

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was after

Answer (score 0):

Using `XmlDocument` class you can just select the "Item" nodes and iterate through the attributes:

```
string myXml = "<RootNode><Item Name=\"Bill\" Age=\"34\" Job=\"Lorry Driver\" Married=\"Yes\" /><Item FavouriteColour=\"Blue\" Age=\"12\" /><Item Job=\"Librarian\" /></RootNode>"
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(myXml);
XmlNodeList itemNodes = doc.SelectNodes("RootNode/Item");
foreach(XmlNode node in itemNodes)
{
    XmlAttributeCollection attributes = node.Attributes;
    foreach(XmlAttribute attr in attributes)
    {
         // Do something...
    }
}
```

Or, if you want an object containing only the Attributes as List of KeyValuePairs, you could use something like:

```
var items = from XmlNode node in itemNodes
            select new 
            {
                Attributes = (from XmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes
                              select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(attr.Name, attr.Value)).ToList()
            };
```

Comment: Thanks I have existing xml parsing code but wanted to see if I can use the xml serialization as it is much neater, I have it working for everything except for the attributes- I know how to do it with known named attributes its the issue of unknown quantity or attribute names