# Deserializing xml attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I'm using XmlSerializer to deserialize an xml document into some class objects. Is there a way to deserialize a node's attributes into a dictionary of key/values rather than having to name properties for each attribute? Example:

```
public class Panel {

    public Dictionary<string, string> AllAttributes {get;set;}

    [XmlElement("image", typeof(Image))]
    [XmlElement("panel", typeof(Panel))]
    public object[] Items { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deserialize element with list of attributes in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884364/how-to-deserialize-element-with-list-of-attributes-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The answer to [How to deserialize element with list of attributes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884364/how-to-deserialize-element-with-list-of-attributes-in-c-sharp/32886092#32886092) demonstrates converting a `Dictionary<string, string>` to an arbitrary list of attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Implement your own serializer.
2. Implement a mapping function:

   - Use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize to a temporary variable (e.g. `var temp`) instead of directly into your class.
   - Call the mapping function passing it the temporary variable `temp`. This function creates a new instance of your `Panel` class, then loops through the `temp` properties and maps them to this instance, and finally it returns the new instance.