# XML Serialization of Unknown Attributes in .NET Core

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, .net-core

Over the past day or so I have been upgrading my application to .NET Core, `netcoreapp1.0`, from `net451`. Most of the process went very well and everything is ported over minus one issue I am seeing.

I was using `System.Xml` and `System.Xml.Serialization` to serialize XML from an API endpoint (which I have absolutely no control over). It was working well, but, due to an issue with the XML, there was always one attribute that came back as an `UnknownAttribute`. I handled it by wiring to the `UknownAttribute` event like this:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonDetails));

var personDetails = (PersonDetails)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

serializer.UnknownAttribute += new XmlAttributeEventHandler((object sender, XmlAttributeEventArgs e) => {
    unknownAttr.Add(e.Attr.Name, e.Attr.Value);
});

// Handle the missing map value if it exists.
string addressValue;
if(unknownAttr.TryGetValue("Address_x0_", out addressValue))
{
    personDetails.Address = addressValue;
}
```

With the upgrade to .NET Core, I now use the [System.Xml.XmlSerializer 4.0.11](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.XmlSerializer/) library. Now, it appears that the UnknownAttribute event is no longer part of the `XmlSerializer` anymore. I have been unable to find another way to handle unknown attributes and would appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: From the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyattributeattribute) it looks like dotnetcore still supports [`XmlAnyAttributeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyattributeattribute.aspx).  You could add an `[XmlAnyAttribute]` property to your `PersonDetails` class along the lines of the one in [How to deserialize element with list of attributes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884364) and look for your unknown attribute inside.

Comment: Thanks @dbc. I did see that, but, when I try that example, `XmlAttribute[]` is not a type. Don't know if I'm missing a library or if something is seriously broken on my end. I have `XmlAttributeAttribute`, `XmlAttributes`, and `XmlAttributeOverrides`. Nothing else with `XmlAttribute`. Any idea? EDIT: I also see it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.xml#System_Xml_XmlAttribute, but, it doesn't compile when I attempt to use it.

Comment: You may need this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.XmlDocument/

Comment: @dbc That's what did it. If you want to make that your answer, I'll accept. It seems strange to me that the packaging is split apart, even though the namespace is System.Xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using an unknown attribute event, you can add a `public XmlAttribute[] XmlAttributes` property to your `PersonDetails`, mark it with [`[XmlAnyAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.aspx), and handle the unknown attribute there:

```
public class PersonDetails
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyAttribute]
    public XmlAttribute[] XmlAttributes
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                foreach (var attr in value)
                    if (attr.Name == "Address_x0_")
                        Address = attr.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you found, you will need to add https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.XmlDocument/ to make use of `XmlAttribute` in .NET Core.